# Open/Delete/Replace then save to CSV

Tags: excel, vbscript, save

I have VBA code that will open a file, delete and replace certain things and then save it to a CSV file. I opened a new Excel workbook and recorded all the steps mentioned above. I then saved this to a .xlsm file, so when it gets clicked it does its job.

However, I want to make a VBScript that will do the same thing. Basically have a VBScript that will open the .xls file, clean it up, and then save it to a .csv file that could be open in Excel.

Here is my VBA:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 ChDir "C:\_deletelater\xls"
 Workbooks.OpenText filename:="C:\_deletelater\xls\traxreport.xls", Origin:= _
     437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
     ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
     , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
     TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("A1:AD18").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Replace What:="DYN", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="WOO", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="MIS", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="BAS", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="BAR", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="DLC", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
 Selection.Replace What:="SYN", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
     ReplaceFormat:=False
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\_deletelater\xls\traxreport.csv", _
     FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
 ActiveWorkbook.Save
If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
   ThisWorkbook.Save
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example code, pretty much all your code will work as you have it except you need to create the missing objects Excel provides in the macro editor.

This is the base for the code that would be put into a VBS file.

```
    dim Application : Set Application = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Application.Visible=true ' OPTIONAL debug line to show excel
Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' MOVED should happen at start to prevent msgboxes.
dim Workbooks : Set Workbooks= Application.Workbooks ' to support direct calls
dim Selection ' needs to be set after each change it appears

' alter the next line to open your work book (return value from "OpenText")
' instead of to add a new one (was for my test)
dim WorkBook : Set Workbook = Workbooks.add()
dim sheet : Set sheet=Workbook.sheets(1) ' ADDED! first work sheet in the book.

msgbox "Just a msg to pause execution, remove this"

' your cremaining code here from your question ...
' Replace all "Range(" calls with "Workbook.Range("
' Replace "ActiveWorkbook" with "Workbook" to be more specific
' You will also need to translate all the constants such as 
' "xlDelimited" into there equivalent numerical values which 
' you can see in the object browser in excel's VBA Editor.

Application.Quit
```

full proposed macro code below ...

```
dim Application : Set Application = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Application.Visible=true 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' MOVED should happen at start to prevent msgboxes.
dim Workbooks : Set Workbooks= Application.Workbooks
dim Selection ' set later (after each selection)

dim WorkBook : Set Workbook = Workbooks.add("C:\_deletelater\xls\traxreport.xls")
dim sheet : Set sheet=Workbook.sheets(1) ' first work sheet in the book.

sheet.Range("A1:AD18").Select                          ' CHANGED!
Set Selection = Application.Selection ' COPIED / REAPPLIED
Selection.Delete -4162 ' xlUp = -4162
sheet.Columns("A:A").Select ' added ".Select"              ' CHANGED!
Set Selection = Application.Selection ' COPIED / REAPPLIED
Selection.Replace "DYN", "", 2, 1, False, False, False
Selection.Replace "WOO", "", 2, 1, False, False, False
Selection.Replace "MIS", "", 2, 1, False, False, False
Selection.Replace "BAS", "", 2, 1, False, False, False
Selection.Replace "BAR", "", 2, 1, False, False, False
Selection.Replace "DLC", "", 2, 1, False, False, False
Selection.Replace "SYN", "", 2, 1, False, False, False
WorkBook.SaveAs "C:\_deletelater\xls\traxreport.csv", 6, False
Workbook.Save     ' xlCSV = 6
If Workbook.Saved = False Then
    Workbook.Save
End If
Workbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Quit
```

Comment: Sorry you will need a few more objects to support "Range" and "Selection" I will update the example in a few minutes.

Comment: Hey thanks it helped alot! but now its not letting me run it due to the Selection.Replace.... any ideas? i will put what i have done so far

Comment: @DarrenMB - what about the named parameters that are illegal in VBScript?

Comment: Think needed "workbook.Columns("A:A").SELECT" method call to allow replace to occur.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner yeah missed a few. still editing. just noticed the xlUP

Comment: Replaced all the named parameters "Name:=Value" (VBS doesn't support this as poointed out by @Ekkehard.Horner )

Comment: +1 - deserved for the fixing of the named parameters alone (not to mention the rest).

Comment: Thank you, I actually got my code just before checking this, however for somereason when i run it I get an error saying "Object doesnt support method: 'Range'" Anyone?

Comment: Need to see the line in question. basically your calling ".Range(" on something that doesn't have a range property. hopefully just a minor mistake / cut and paste mistake.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Normally in VBA coding you don't work with the "Selection" range as it can be interfered with by the user. Maybe try defining a Range object and set then work with that object instead. Dim r : set r = Workbook.Range("A1:AD18") : r.delete -4162 : set r = Workbook.Columns("A:A") : r.Replace .... ....

Comment: Hey I've tried that and still nothing... Still gives me the same error, I also do not see anything wrong with the code. Again thanks for all the help, first time messing with this stuff.

Comment: I updated the code again. I ran it locally against my own test sheet and it does get all the way through now. The issue was the range object was being used against the "book" not the "sheet" I didn't notice I did that origianlly.

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly!!!! Can't believe we missed that!! Hey is there any way to make this run automatically without clicking on it?

Comment: Schedule it with Task Scheduler under a specific user account, and run regardless of the user being logged in or not. If your running on 2008 Server background tasks using Excel may have some difficulty unless you make some configuration changes. Also the user may need to login once manually and start each office application to ensure it operates correctly (and all one-time prompts are dealt with)

Comment: Mark it as answer please, I put allot of work into this one :)